# User doesn't answers if they see there are replies on a Question

Tags: feature-request

I have been on stackoverflow and also gone through number of Questions from which i observed that if there are replies on a Question then, Users other then who have replied,  it may seems to them that the Question is answered and might possibly ignore that.

My suggestion would be that there should be some **Flag** or Possibly anything that the user would have to choose if they got the answer of their Question in the replies and if not then to other users it should look as unaswered.

thank you

Comment: if the answered it not accepted, to the other users it seems it is answered. might be a possibility that user has willingly not accepted the answer. Even if the person who has raised the Question got his/her answer

Comment: Indeed, there is no way we can read the mind of the asker as yet. We do have to wait till they tell us.

Answer (score 6):

That's what the green tick is for. It makes an answer as accepted which means that, from the OP's perspective, he got his solution. Questions with accepted answers show up in a green filled box and a number count of answers. Questions with no accepted answers but some answers show up in a white filled number-bearing box. Questions with no answers have a 0

> [image]
>
> [image]

There is still merit in answering a question with an accepted answer; occasionally I've been able to post an answer sufficiently better than the accepted answer, to get the OP to change acceptable to my answer even though they already accepted someone else's. Adding an answer to an a question already marked accepted doesn't prohibit you from getting points via other people upvoting your answer

There is more merit in answering a question that has no accepted answer; some people post absolute carp as answers so seeing that a question has answers doesn't put experienced users off from checking the question anyway. If I enter a question that has answers, I may check on them, comment on them and upvote or downvote some as a way of informing the OP which answers I think are helpful or not. This allows me to easily share my opinion on which answer I think should be accepted without having to write my own. If the answers there are wrong or insufficient, I add my own

If a user posts a question and it gets answers that aren't good enough they could  refine the question and post a bounty on it as a way of flagging to other users that question remains and hasn't had good answers, and trying to generate further interest. Anyone can bounty a question

It's known that a lot of users don't accept any answer to trheir question; it's not that they didn't use the solution provided, it's that they didn't know how to use the site. You can see the dev team trying to combat this by putting tooltips in. If as an OP I upvote an answer but don't accept it I see a nag that if it's my solution I should green tick it..

---

You're raising a point about the psychology of users too- yes I do tend to spend my precious time looking into questions with 0 answers. I also have gotten to know who the pros are in the tags I inhabit most. If I see the likes of Gordon Linoff, Tim Biegeliesen, fa06, a_horse_with_no_name, Zaynul etc *commenting* on or editing a question I don't bother answering because the likelihood that they will post an excellent answer (and something I would have recommended to do also l, anyway) is high/imminent so I go find another question to answer. There isn't much you can do to control my psychology - I'm trying to help as many people as possible and that makes me focus on 0 answer questions first, answered but not accepted second

You're up against a lot. All you can do is use the site as it was intended: post a good question, respond to comments, and mark an answer as accepted if it's good for you

Perhaps there is something that could be done; color the answer box yellow if one or more answers has received at least one upvote. This could help distinguish between questions with no answers considered good and questions that have one or more good answers (as voted by the community) that haven't hit the spot for the OP